# Interface for Array Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have made an interface for [Velocityjs](http://velocityjs.org/) so I can use it in TypeScript, but I'm not sure how to correctly make interfaces for array types. This is a function for making calls[] for the Velocity.RegisterEffect method from the Velocity UI Pack:

```
let calls: [{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }][] = keyFramesProps.map((p: string): [{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }] => {
    let anim: KeyFrameSlitted = keyFramesSlitted[p];
    let durationPercentage = (+p.replace('%', '')) * 0.01;
    return [anim.props, durationPercentage, anim.options];
});
```

So I want to make an interface for the type: `[{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }]`

This was the only thing that worked:

```
interface VelocityCall extends Array<any>{
    [0]: { [key: string]: any };
    [1]: number;
    [2]: { easing?: string, delay?: number };
}
```

I needed to extend Array, if not the compiler complained about missing methods on the array.

Now I can do this:

```
let calls: VelocityCall[] = keyFramesProps.map((p: string): VelocityCall => {
        let anim: KeyFrameSlitted = keyFramesSlitted[p];
        let durationPercentage = (+p.replace('%', '')) * 0.01;
        return [anim.props, durationPercentage, anim.options];
    });
```

Here is the rest of the Velocity interface (without the VelocityCall) if someone else need it or have a better solution:

```
interface VelocityOptions extends Object {

    queue?: string;
    duration?: number | "slow" | "normal" | "fast";
    easing?: string;
    begin?: any;
    complete?: any;
    progress?: any;
    display?: undefined | string;
    visibility?: undefined | string;
    loop?: boolean;
    delay?: number | boolean;
    mobileHA?: boolean;
    /* Advanced: Set to false to prevent property values from being cached between consecutive Velocity-initiated chain calls. */
    _cacheValues?: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;

}

interface Velocity {
    (element: Element, propertiesMap: "fadeIn" | "fadeOut" | "slideUp" | "slideDown" | "scroll" | "reverse" | "finish" | "finishAll" | "stop" | { [key: string]: any }, options?: VelocityOptions): Promise<Response>;
    RegisterEffect(name: string, effect: {
        defaultDuration?: number;
        calls: [{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }][] | [{ [key: string]: any }, number][] | [{ [key: string]: any }][];
        reset: { [key: string]: any }
    });
}

declare var Velocity: Velocity;
```

Comment: It should be `[{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }]` without the extra `[]` at the end, based on the `VelocityCall` interface you posted

Comment: Sorry, I removed the []. That was an array of VelocityCalls (copy past mistake)

Comment: And what errors do you get when you use this form? When I do this: `let a: [{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }];` I get all of the array methods for variable `a`.

Comment: I was asking about the correct way of making an interface for that type, and if there was a better way than extending Array<any>. Try to use the VelocityCall interface without the extends Array<any>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing matches the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) as you want to describe an array of a specific length with specific types per index.

Instead of using an interface you can (and probably should) use:

```
type VelocityCall = [{ [key: string]: any }, number, { easing?: string, delay?: number }];
```